# Pay 3rd Party With PayPal API

Tags: php, api, paypal

I'm developing an application which pays out payments to a 3rd party. The source code for what I'm using is found here:

http://paypal.github.io/PayPal-PHP-SDK/sample/doc/payments/CreateThirdPartyPayment.html

I've added the following as well for my ClientID and Client Secret:

```
$apiContext = new \PayPal\Rest\ApiContext(
    new \PayPal\Auth\OAuthTokenCredential(
        'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',     // ClientID
        'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'      // ClientSecret
    )
);
```

When using my sandbox credentials, the code succeeds as it should. When swapping to the live credentials, however, I get an invalid client, authentication failed error. I've ensure the live ClientID and Client Secret are exactly what I have on my developer portal.

I've been looking all over the developer portal looking for a possible setting I'm missing, or something not configured correctly but have come to a loss. Any advice?

Update: I also don't see any issues/errors on the developer portal when logged into developer.paypal.com

Update 2:
I found this just now:

```
public function setConfig(array $config)
{
   PayPalConfigManager::getInstance()->addConfigs($config);
}
```

Do I need to set the config by `$apiContext->setConfig('LIVE')` (or something to this effect?)

Comment: Did you also change the `$payee->setEmail`

Comment: Yes I did. I have that set to my personal email.

Comment: Did you check if you switched to live mode in your config file?

Comment: @JashParekh - The SDK I have doesn't have a config file, but I did find a setConfig method. (I updated my question).

Answer (score 2):

With the assistance from @JashParakh I was able to solve the issue. I added the following:

```
$config['mode'] = 'Live';
$apiContext->setConfig($config);
```

The payment went through in live and is should have.